# Magento2.2 default storeview error store id not found

Tags: htaccess, magento2.2

I have created 2 store views in magento latest 2.2

I have enabled add store view to url in settings.

But on home page it throws error store id not found.

If I add en/ at the end of url or ar/ at end it works fine.

Even the language switcher is working fine.

Only issue with home page.

How can I set the default storeview for home page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with updating the default switcher model found in 
/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreManager.php. So I created a new module and in di.xml i wrote

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <preference for="Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager" type="Vendor\Custom\Model\StoreManager" />


</config>
```

and Then in my new Storemanager code I added the below code.

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Vendor\Custom\Model;

/**
 * Service contract, which manage scopes
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class StoreManager extends \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getStore($storeId = null)
    {
//        echo $storeId;
//        die('000');
        if (!isset($storeId) || '' === $storeId || $storeId === true) {
            if (null === $this->currentStoreId) {
                \Magento\Framework\Profiler::start('store.resolve');
                $this->currentStoreId = $this->storeResolver->getCurrentStoreId();
                \Magento\Framework\Profiler::stop('store.resolve');
            }
            $storeId = $this->currentStoreId;
        }
        if ($storeId instanceof \Magento\Store\Api\Data\StoreInterface) {
            return $storeId;
        }
        if (!$storeId) {
            if (isset($_COOKIE['store']) && $_COOKIE['store'] !== '') {
                $storeId = $_COOKIE['store'];
            } else {
                $storeId = $this->getDefaultStoreView()->getCode();
            }
        }
        $store = is_numeric($storeId)
            ? $this->storeRepository->getById($storeId)
            : $this->storeRepository->get($storeId);

        return $store;
    }
}
```

This is a bug already reported.